# Using multiple filter to get data from two tables using django rest frame work

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to django and trying to get data from two tables who are joined by a forigen key.

Below is my query:

```
 processes = ServiceWorkOrder.objects.filter(service_id=service_id).filter(ServiceWorkOrder.workdata == WorkFlowOrder.id).select_related('workdata')
```

My models are:

```py
class WorkFlowOrder(AbstractModel):
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM'),
        ('CUSTOMER', 'CUSTOMER'),
        ('AGENT', 'AGENT'),
        ('CUSTOMER_SUPPORT', 'CUSTOMER_SUPPORT')
    )
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    trigger_on_rejection = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    action_detail = models.CharField(max_length=500)  # in hours
    email_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sms_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mailer_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fax_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assignee = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=USER_TYPE, null=True, default=None)
    notify_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notify_customer_support = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "WorkFlowOrder"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'WorkFlowOrder is %s action_name%s action_detail : %s' % (self.action_name, self.action_detail, self.id)


class ServiceWorkOrder(AbstractModel):
    service_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    workdata = models.ForeignKey(WorkFlowOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    generic_work_order_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    sequence_num = models.CharField(max_length=500)  # in hours
    email_template_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    sms_template_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    mailer_job_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    fax_template_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    dcg_email_template_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ServiceWorkOrder"
```

Please help me to get data from both tables.
Although it works fine when I use only one filter of service_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `ServiceWorkOrder` and `WorkFlowOrder` data using a loop, as below.

```py
service_id = 12345
orders = ServiceWorkOrder.objects.filter(service_id=service_id)

for order in orders:
    print(order.service_id)
    print(order.workdata.id)
    print(order.workdata.action_name)
```

Comment: If u see there is another filter which is comparing id of one table shall be equal to id of another table.. Else it will fetch unrelated data also.

Comment: I saw that, but, I don't think you will get any unrelated data if you use this answer